# Where does Firefox save images, by default?

Tags: linux, macos, firefox, hyperlink

Firefox has the prominent configurable option where to save files when I select the "Save Link As" action. However, this does not seem to apply to images I want to download by right-clicking them in an already rendered webpage. I.e. the file download directory is `~/Downloads` -- which I believe is the "factory default" -- but Firefox offers to save images somewhere like `/run/user/1000/doc/deadbeef` . To be sure, I can change the directory in the Save dialog, but Firefox doesn't *remember* my selection, at least on Linux (it does on Mac, probably because it uses some precooked code from the Mac UI). So if I want to download many images from the same page, I have to navigate to my desired destination directory every time :cry:

My question is: Why is this, why is the initial image directory different from the regular download directory, and can I change / configure this?

P.S. It is possible that the odd `/run/user` directory is just the current directory for Firefox when I run it from the Gnome shell. But that doesn't help because I don't control where that is.

Comment: Doesn't happen on Windows. Which version is your Firefox? Have you tried to reinstall it?

Comment: Firefox seems to remember a number of previous location for that kind of download (images, pdf...) for that site/page. Different pair of page/type different location. BTW from the upper part of the download window it should be able to change the path, click on the right and it may transform the current path in a textbox editable. Else you can navigate or specify it before the filename.

Comment: @hastur first of all, I am not even sure we're talking about the same thing. PDFs are usually regular links, so saving them works like saving other linked stuff. I am talking about images that are not links, but displayed normally inline. The use case is like a gallery website, does it make sense? And that also explains why it isn't acceptable to edit the directory again and again for each image, it is too repetitive.

Comment: @harrymc as I noted it doesn't happen on Mac either. Just on Linux with Gnome. My version is 114.0.1 but I think I remember it was always like this; it's just that now I see how bad it actually is :(

Comment: My version is 114.0.2. Try to have it updated, or get it from [here](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/114.0.2/mac/en-US/).

Comment: @harrymc sorry, you don't get it. I'm not a newbie, and this behavior has been there for as long as I remember (though the initial directory itself depends on the system environment). But thanks for trying. Edit: so are you saying when you right click on an image and pick "Save Image As..." the dialog you get starts with your Downloads directory? Just making sure you understand what my problem is.

Comment: In my case on Windows, the Save dialog uses the last-used folder that I specified in Firefox, for all kinds of elements. What are your *Settings > General > Downloads
Save files to*? Have you tried to uninstall Firefox, clean up all folders and reinstall?

Comment: @harrymc really. Your goal seem to be mostly to diss me?

Comment: Truly not, but this behavior is puzzling. Last thoughts: You might examine `about:config` or get the latest version from `mozilla.org`. I won't be offering more suggestions, promise.